# React Hooks Form : undefined values on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I took the example from the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/v5/api/) :

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  console.log(watch("example")); 

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input defaultValue="test" {...register("example")} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

But on every change or on submit, I got `undefined` for each field

[image]

I tried to install the library again but nothing change and I got undefined everywhere...seems to be a problem with the register function. Does anybody got the same issue ?

Comment: What version of react-hook form are you using?

Comment: hi, you can check https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch. you should add manually in your watch values when you make submit it takes values normally in submit

Comment: I use the version 6.15.5

Comment: Please update to latest e.g. 7.4.2, v6 is not working with that way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With v7 the usage of `register` changed as noted in the comments. If you still need to use v6, you have to write it like this:

```
function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  console.log(watch("example")); 

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input defaultValue="test" name="example" ref={register} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

[Docs v6](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#watch)

[image: Edit React Hook Form - register v6]

Comment: I'll check that and let you know. Thx

Comment: Thx again. This indeed was the problem

Answer (score 17):

In my case it was a typo:

```
<input defaultValue="test" {...(register('name'), { required: true })} />

// submit => { name: undefined }
```

Instead of:

```
<input defaultValue="test" {...(register('name', { required: true }))} />

// submit => { name: "test" }
```

Hopefully it can help someone else.

Comment: +10!! this is such an easy mistake to make. I had to carefully spot the difference in your code!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when using the Input component from reactstrap. Using that component made all my values undefined. I switch the Input to a normal input and was able to read in values

Before:

```
<Input 
                placeholder="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                defaultValue=""
                {...register('password')}
                required
              />
```

Fixed:

```
<input 
                placeholder="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                defaultValue=""
                {...register('password')}
                required
              />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was removing the ref I had on my `<input />`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using a Controller, so to fix the Undefined value I just had to pass defaultValues to useForm.
See the rules section here: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch

```
 const { register, handleSubmit, control, setValue} = useForm<MyFormValues>({
    defaultValues : {
      receiveUpdates: false
    }
  });

<Controller
  control={control}
  name="receiveUpdates"
  render={({ field }) => (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          ref={field.ref}
          checked={field.value}
          onChange={field.onChange}
        />
      }
      label="Receive Email Updates?"
      labelPlacement="start"
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I installed like "npm i react-hook-form" and I don't know why, but it was installed ^6.15.8 version, and I removed it and try again and then it was install correctly. So try to check out your version of react-hook-form